# Checed checkboxes based on ids and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i'm trying to make something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/WFXun/

but instead of fadeout checkboxes on click, i want to mark checked only the checkboxes defined by ids (var ids = [2,3,5,6];) when the page is loaded.

I was trying this and it does not work:

```
$("#set_1").load(function(){
     var ids = [2,3,5,6];
        for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            $("#set_"+ids[i]).prop("checked", true);
    }
})
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: What is the purpose of `$("#set_1").load(…)` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the load you want

```
$("#set_1").load(function(){
```

That is for loading content with an Ajax request.

You want to bind to window load or document ready.

```
$(window).load( function() {
  ids.forEach( function (id) {
    $("#set_"+id).prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

Comment: `$(window).load(…)` was removed in favor of .ready in jQuery 3.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the JavaScript console shows your problem.

1. You want to use `$().click`, not `$().load`.
2. The linked fiddle does not support `$().prop`, so it must be changed to `.attr` or use a newer jQuery version.

This code works:

```
$("#set_1").click(function(){
     var ids = [2,3,5,6];
        for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            $("#set_"+ids[i]).attr("checked", true);
    }
})
```

This is also an alternative solution to your issue:

```js
var idMap = {
    1: [2, 3, 5, 6],
    2: [4, 7]
};

function onClick(id, idsToToggle) {
    var checked = $("#set_" + id).prop("checked");
    idsToToggle
        .map(function(id) { return $("#set_" + id); })
        .forEach(function(el) { el.prop("checked", checked) });
}

$(function() {
    Object.keys(idMap).forEach(function(id) {
        $("#set_" + id).click(onClick.bind(this, id, idMap[id]));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="set_1">checkbox 1</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="set_2">checkbox 2</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="set_3">checkbox 3</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="set_4">checkbox 4</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="set_5">checkbox 5</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="set_6">checkbox 6</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="set_7">checkbox 7</p>
```

It allows you to have more flexibility if you decide to add more checkbox mappings, you can simply edit the `idMap`.

Comment: thanks! this is working:

$( document ).ready(function() {
     var ids = [3,5,6];
        for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            $("#set_"+ids[i]).attr("checked", true);
    }
})

Comment: @Kay - You are correct, however the linked JSFiddle seemed not to support the `prop` function. Perhaps as it was using an old version of jQuery. I have revised my answer.

Comment: @CosmicDisco - Great! I also added another solution to the answer, if that is better for your use case. If this answer or any other worked, please make sure to accept it.